# Why does the null values of age are not filled even though i filled them?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I had to fill the null values in age column. I did some analysis and formed a code to do this. i ran the code but still there is no change in the data.

```py
for index,i in df[df['Age'].isna()==True].iterrows():
    pc = i['Pclass']
    ss = i['SibSp']
    i['Age'] = df[(df['Pclass']==pc ) & (df['SibSp']==ss)]['Age'].mean()
```

Comment: You should edit you question to add more context on how your program work what is not working. With such a small snippet of code, it's difficult to tel what's wrong.

Comment: If you can provide more information, like  a sample of your dataframe, and perhaps a sample output, we could help you better.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are trying to fill the missing `Age` values with `mean` value of those age which are available `Age`. If that is the case, simply do this.

```
df['Age'] = df['Age'].fillna(df['Age'].mean(), axis=0)
```

or, as @JonClements suggested below, use `inplace`

```
df['Age'].fillna(df['Age'].mean(), inplace=True)
```

Comment: You can also use: `df['Age'].fillna(df['Age'].mean(), inplace=True)`

Comment: Yes, thanks @JonClements for adding this.

Comment: Feel free to add it to your answer as an alternative